# Не полностью выводятся товары в jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Есть data.json и есть картинки в каждой которой есть слог **_tn** хочу чтобы выводился список товаров c этими картинками, но почему-то только выводятся название и цена, а картинки не выводятся, объясните что не так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
    var output = '<ul class="main-content">';
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        output += '<li>';
        output += '<h2>' + val.name +'</h2>';
        output += '<img src="../img/">' + '_tn.jpg' + val.price;
      output += '</li>';
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#update').html(output);
})
```

Comment: `output += '<img src="../img/' + val.price +'_tn.jpg">';`

Comment: @Igor NaN. Выводиться теперь

Comment: какие названия у картинок?

Comment: @Igor 1, 2  и в каждой конце _tn.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
    output += '<li>';
    output += '<h2>' + val.name +'</h2>';
    output += '<img src="../img/' + (key + 1) + '_tn.jpg">' + val.price;
    output += '</li>';
});
```

Comment: Цены начали выводиться,  но картинки до сих пор не выводяться, не понимаю ведь путь к файлам верный был прописан из js папки в папку img. Сейчас ради интереса создал новый файл index.html на локалхосте и все работает скрин https://imgur.com/a/Vqdwanh

Comment: @Остин путь к картинкам должен указываться не относительно js файла, а относительно файла страницы

Comment: Чет совсем не понимаю в одном файле index.html пишет     
 1_tn.jpg:1 GET http://localhost/img/1_tn.jpg 404 (Not Found)  В другом же все работал. Все находиться в одном катологе

Comment: @Остин Мы переходим к гаданию. Добавляйте инфopмацию в вопрос.

Comment: А все понял не относительно js файла, Спасибо за помощь!